# django haystack and join SearchResult

Tags: django-haystack

I have a little probleme with Haystack.

I have a search form and when it's submited,i do a research in 3 models, so I simply use :

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Video,User,PlayList).auto_query(query)
```

Now i need to filter() objects from PlayList's model.
but if i do :

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Video,User).auto_query(query).models(PlayList).auto_query(query).filter(
             Q(user=request.user)| 
             Q(user__userprofilepermission__playlist='all'))
```

The filter() will be used for the 3 models (as written in the doc).

So I think to do that :

```
result1 = SearchQuerySet().models(Video,User).auto_query(query)
result2 = SearchQuerySet().models(PlayList).auto_query(query).filter(
                 Q(user=request.user)| 
                 Q(user__userprofilepermission__playlist='all'))
```

But I want to return juste one variable, and I don't know how to join result1&result2.

Anyone has an idea ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuerySets tend to be glorified lists so a quick way to do this would be:

```
results = list(result1)
results.extend(list(result2))
```